# Facebook Get Friends print_r for each name

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

Here is my code so far:

```
$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
print_r($friends);
```

I want to print just the names.

I noticed when I did the following

```
print_r($friends[data][1][name]);
```

I would get the name of 1 person

How can I turn the 1 into a variable and then have that go to how ever many friends I have so I can get a long list of just my friends names?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over the results of the api call.

```
$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
foreach($friends['data'] as $friend) {
    print_r($friend['name']);
}
```

Comment: This is perfect. I'll check this answer once the 10 minutes passes.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the key / values of the array in a loop, such as foreach.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp

---

```
/* limit sets query to maximum of 5000 friends */
/* only query data we need using &fields=id,name*/
$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends?limit=5000&fields=id,name');
foreach ($friends as $key=>$value){
   foreach($value as $gkey=>$gvalue){
   $friendid = $gvalue[id];
   $friendname = $gvalue[name];
   echo '<div>';
   echo $friendname;
   echo '<br />';
   echo $friendid;
   echo '</div>';
   }
}
```